# Updated to next Xcode getting compiler warning Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this new warning since updating Xcode: Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'title'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention. This is for

```
@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSString *title;
```

in a UIView controller I have subclassed. Does anyone know what this warning means and how I can get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Auto+property+synthesis+will+not+synthesize+property)?

Comment: I did but didn't find anything like my code. Wondering if it's because UIViewController has a property called title. I am actually storing in image title in that variable though and it has worked fine before.

Comment: Since your controller's `title` property is meant to be a different property than the standard `title` property of `UIViewController` you really need to rename your property to avoid a name conflict.

Comment: Yes that message is confusing but it's complaining about the property name collision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIViewController` already has a [property called `title`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) that is available in read/write.  Your custom property, having the same name, is foreshadowing it.  The compiler then raises this error as if you were redeclaring an accessor method (instead of using @dynamic).  You should rename your custom property.